# Azure DevOps Failed to update App Service configuration details

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-web-app-service, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a WebApp in Azure DevOps and I am getting this error:

> [warning]Failed to update App Service configuration details. Error: Error: Failed to update App service 'webapp' configuration. Error: BadRequest - Required parameter AccessKey is missing.

I can't figure out why this is happening, it was working originally and the error came about the other day. Nothing has changed with the WebApp code, no new settings were added. The artifact goes into place and the website works but I get this error, then on another run, the pipeline will fail, so I only have one successful run, then I have to go and delete the web app to have another successful run.

Here is my YAML Code:

```html
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
pr: none
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Website
      name: VALUE/Website
      path:
        - include: /Website
      type: git
      ref: VALUE
variables:
  System.Debug: false
  azureSubscription: VALUE
  RG: rg_example
  Location: UK South
  containername: private
  appconnectionname: VALUE
stages:
  - stage: build_website_files
    displayName: Building Main Website Files
    jobs:
      - job: job1
        displayName: Create And Publish Artifact
        steps:
          - checkout: Website
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: 'mkdir Website' 
              workingDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: 'echo $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Website' 
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: dotnet restore
            inputs:
              command: restore
              projects: Website.csproj
          - task: NodeTool@0
            displayName: Install Node .js
            inputs:
              versionSpec: 14.17.3
              force32bit: false
              checkLatest: false
          - script: |
              npm install -g @angular/cli@12.1.3
              npm install
              ng build --prod
            displayName: npm install and build
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: dotnet build
            inputs:
              projects: Website.csproj
              arguments: '--configuration Release'
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: dotnet restore unit tests
            inputs:
              command: restore
              projects: UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: dotnet Test
            inputs:
              command: test
              projects: UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj
              arguments: '--configuration Release'
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: dotnet publish
            inputs:
              command: publish
              projects: Website.csproj
              arguments: --configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Website
              zipAfterPublish: true
              modifyOutputPath: false
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: Publish Pipeline Artifact
            inputs:
              targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Website
              artifact: Website
              publishLocation: pipeline
  - stage: put_website_files_into_place
    displayName: website_files_into_place
    dependsOn: build_website_files
    jobs:
      - job: job2
        displayName: Create Web App
        #dependsOn: job1
        steps:
          - download: none
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            displayName: Download Build Artifacts
            inputs:
              patterns: '**/*.zip'
              path: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Website/
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: value'
            inputs:
              package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              ConnectedServiceName: $(appconnectionname)
              appName: value
              ResourceGroupName: $(RG)
```

Comment: I have the same issue and looking into it.

Comment: I believed I fixed this by taking the same code, in a fresh yaml file and hooking that up as a new pipeline in Azure DevOps.